# Update config of SearchProvider of ElasticSearch

Tags: reactjs, elasticsearch

I am using `<SearchProvider config={configToUse}>`

**I have 2 configs with different apiConnector. The problem is that when I update configToUse from config1 to config2 elastic search continues to use config1.**

One solution I tried is to put a key, but it has 2 issues.

1. Ugly rerender
2. The search term into search box is deleted and I have no idea how to set it.

Ideally I am looking if I can perform the search programmatically where I put my config or if there is any prop which updates config of SearchProvider.